# how to using web activity in data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to implement one report using Lookup activity and Web activity.

Lookup activity having output from store procedure with multiple records like below

Name ActiveRecords Active
Abc  500             0
XYZ  300             200

Something like the above I have output from the procedure and then I have to use this on web activity.
Also, I am having exciting web activity and I have appended it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Created ADF pipeline as shown below,
   [image]
2. In Lookup activity calling sql stored procedure as shown below,
   [image]
3. Output of lookup activity as shown below,
   [image]
4. The output of Lookup activity is using in web as

```
@string(activity('Lookup').output)
```

[image]
5. Debug the pipeline and it is taking output of lookup as shown below,
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for updating this. Just a question , how you have format the output of look shown above , is it in JSON format.

Comment: Lookup activity is calling stored procedure and output of Lookup activity is in Json format. In web activity I am converting it to string syntax @string(activity('Lookup').output)